# In Ember, transition.retry() doesn't send query string params

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a route mixin that will check if the user is authenticated and if not, take them to the login page. Once they login, I redirect them back to the page they initially tried to go to. I'm using Ember's [suggested solution](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/#toc_storing-and-retrying-a-transition) for storing and retrying a transition. This works well the way it is. The problem is, when I try to add a query string parameter, it doesn't get passed in the transition.

Now I know I can do [this](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/#toc_transitionto) but I'd prefer to use the `transition.retry` method instead.

Any ideas?

**Ember's suggested solution**

```
App.SomeAuthenticatedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function(transition) {
    if (!this.controllerFor('auth').get('userIsLoggedIn')) {
      var loginController = this.controllerFor('login');
      loginController.set('previousTransition', transition);
      this.transitionTo('login');
    }
  }
});

App.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    login: function() {
      // Log the user in, then reattempt previous transition if it exists.
      var previousTransition = this.get('previousTransition');
      if (previousTransition) {
        this.set('previousTransition', null);
        previousTransition.retry();
      } else {
        // Default back to homepage
        this.transitionToRoute('index');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**What I'm currently using**

```
this.transitionTo('posts', {queryParams: {sort: 'title'}});
```

Comment: That documentation may change one day and this question won't make any sense. Please copy the code you've linked to into your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue talking about this, and also a related PR been commited. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/4008

Currentlly, `retry` can't pass the query parameters,